# How does soundcloud generate their html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today I was inspecting the soundcloud source-html through chrome, but it only returned a basic(very small) html dom.

So I was wondering how do they generate their html?
I'm curious because soundcloud is a pretty big website and I doubt they generate all the html though javascript, but when I checked their javascript I could not find any `<div` tags or anything like that.

Comment: @Dagon : Also this question is off-topic so any moderator should please put it on-hold..!

Comment: I was only asking how they generate that html. I know soundcloud runs on ruby...

Comment: Might I suggest searching the [SoundCloud Developers Blog](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/), you'll probably find quite a bit of info about the kinds of technologies that they use.

Answer (score 2):

For larger dynamic websites usually a template framework is used like EJS - http://www.embeddedjs.com/

With templating you can embed JavaScript logic directly into the HTML so it changes and updates dynamically.

Comment: Well..that's good and +1 for sharing something good but as it may not be the answer to the question..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai I agree completely but I think this question was curiosity on how to achieve a similar effect. Vague question so I could only offer a vague answer

Comment: Still appreciate though your effort to answer the question..!